# Misunderstanding the notion of strict global minimizer

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

I am reading the book "The Mathematics of nonlinear Programming - AL peressini" as a self-student and I am a beginner in this field.

Theorem 1.1.5 states that:

> Suppose that $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$ are all continuous on an interval $I$ and that $x* \in I$ is a critical point of $f(x)$.
>
> (a) If $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in I$, then $x*$ is a global minimizer of $f(x)$ on $I$. 
> (b) If $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$ such that $x \ne x*$, then $x*$ is a strict global minimizer of $f(x)$ on $I$.
> (c) If $f''(x*) > 0$, then $x*$ is a strict local minimizer of $f(x)$.

If I take the function $f(x)=x^4$ for example. Clearly all the conditions from the hypothesis hold and $x*=0$ is a critical point.

Now according to the theorem, (a) and (b) are both true for $f(x)$ and $x*=0$. Therefore $0$ is both a global minimizer and a strict global minimizer of $f(x)$. However, (c) is false since $f''(0)=0$ so $0$ is not a local minimizer of $f(x)$.

But there seems to be a contradiction since a strict global minimizer should also be a strict local minimizer. So I guess I misunderstood (b). Could anyone tell me what I am missing here?

[image capture of theorem 1.1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHS8T.png)

Answer (score 2):

The statement in c) is an implication, not an equivalence. Thus, if $f''(x^*)>0$ is satisfied, then we have a strict local minimum, but if $f''(x^*)>0$ is not satisfied it does not mean that we cannot have a strict local minimum there.

Comment: Thank you very much ajr, I knew I was overlooking something. So obvious!